# Connect to sphinx on remote server

Tags: linux, tcp, remote, sphinxsearch, sphinx

I recently moved sphinx onto the same server as our db so our architecture is:

1. File Server that hosts our web app
2. DB server w/ Sphinx instance (searchd)

When I try to connect to sphinx at `ip.to.db.server` I get the following error:

`Sphinx response connection to ip.to.db.server:9312 failed (errno=113, msg=No route to host)`

Is there something special I need to do to make port 9312 accessible to my web app?

Current `TCP` ports `LISTEN`ing:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      23496/searchd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9312                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      23496/searchd
```

Output of `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) 
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports ssh 
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh /* SSH */ 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:lmsocialserver /* monit */ 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https /* HTTPS */ 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:webcache /* HTTPProxy */ 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http /* HTTP */ 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql /* MySQL */ 
ACCEPT     all  --  ipremoved_by_poster  anywhere            /* Rackspace monitoring */ 
ACCEPT     all  --  ipremoved_by_poster  anywhere            /* Rackspace monitoring */ 
ACCEPT     all  --  ipremoved_by_poster  anywhere            /* Rackspace monitoring */ 
ACCEPT     all  --  ipremoved_by_poster  anywhere            /* Rackspace monitoring */ 
ACCEPT     all  --  ipremoved_by_poster  anywhere            /* Rackspace monitoring */ 
ACCEPT     all  --  ipremoved_by_poster  anywhere            /* Rackspace monitoring */ 
ACCEPT     all  --  ipremoved_by_poster  anywhere            /* Rackspace monitoring */ 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* localhost */ 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any /* ping */ 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I've done lots of searching with no luck so far. Any help is much appreciated.

E

Comment: Looks like a firewall problem....or a networking configuration issue

Comment: What is the output of `iptables -L` on the db server?

Comment: I've updated the post with the output of iptables -L @sciurus

Comment: It's definitely an iptables issue. when i stop iptables my search service works fine. But when i try to add a new rule to accept incoming connections from my web server ip, it doesn't end up in the rules list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was `IPTABLES` was blocking my remote connection so I added two lines to be safe:

`vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables`

add the following lines:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9312 -m comment --comment "Sphinx" -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s your.remote.ip.address/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9312 -j ACCEPT
```

Adjust port `9312` to whichever port/ports you have sphinx listening on.

Then I ran `service iptables restart` and sphinx was a go!

Thanks to @mdpc and @sciurus for pointing me in the right direction.

`NOTE:` Rackspace uses `RH-Firewall-1-INPUT`, but you may need to use just `INPUT`, or something different